# Guzzle POST request to JWT API get Unauthorized while Postman is working

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, postman, guzzle

Guzzle POST request to JWT API get Unauthorized while Postman is working.
Here is the code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new Client();
    $this->connect();
}

public function connect()
{
    $loginResult = $this->client->request('POST', config('api.base_uri') .'/auth/login', [
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => config('api.login'),
            'password' => config('api.password'),
        ]
    ]);

    dd(json_decode($loginResult->getBody()));

}
```

I got 401 Unauthorized while running this code. Credentials are passed correctly.
Meanwhile in Postman it is working perfectly:
[image: While in Postman it is working perfectly]

Kindly advise me what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Following is controller and function this request is hitting in API side:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

        if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized '.$credentials['email']], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
...
```

User does exist as it is working in Postman

**UPDATE 2**
I have simplified code to find that is wrong to:

```
Route::get('/guzzle', function () {
    $client = new Client([
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]]);

    $loginResult =
        $client->request('POST', config('pics.base_uri') .'/auth/login', [
            'form_params' => [
                'email' => '****@****.com',
                'password' => '*****',
            ]
        ]);

    dd(json_decode($loginResult->getBody()));
});
```

And it does not work - got same error

Comment: Try to adding header `Accept: application/json` to your request

Comment: @SaeedVaziry sorry no... It was already discussed below

Comment: The first constructor is in what class?

Comment: @Kyslik it is in Contract from site end which communicates with API

Comment: Contracts are interfaces in Laravel terminology, they do not have constructors nor implementations. Could you please add the whole thing and how you invoke it (or when), I fear that config is not available at the time of constructing thus you are doing request to `/auth/login` and with no credentials - try hardcoding the values in.

Comment: Thanks @Kyslik... following how I'm testing it: `Route::get('/guzzle', function () {    $registraiton = new \App\Registration(new \App\Repositories\Api\ApiRepository); });` where `Registration` implements `ApiRepositoryContract`

Comment: For this kind of testing use tinker mate :). Anyway you do not need to new up stuff, do `$registration = resolve(\App\Registration::class); $registration->connect();` - and of course remove the connect from constructor!

Comment: Hm... still not working :(

Comment: Even with hardcoded values for `api_url`, `login` and `password`?

Comment: Yes... even with hardcoded... actually it makes request correctly therefore I assume that config is available at that time

Comment: tried `dd(config('api.base_uri'));` and got correct URL

Comment: @Kyslik I have posted 2nd update... not in code

Comment: Try this in your controller: or however you test, if you get your ip: `dump((string) (new GuzzleHttp\Client())->get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')->getBody())`

Comment: working and got my IP address

Comment: Try debugging using http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug

Comment: @Kyslik but I tried: `dump((new GuzzleHttp\Client())->post('http://****.local/api/auth/login', ['form_params' => ['email' => '***@***.com','password' => '****',]])->getBody());` got unauthorized

Comment: Go to postman and on right hand side click on cookies and delete all cookies try if you get 200. Again in the postman turn on console (on the bottom left 2 or 3rd button) and try request again and see what is sent to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... after couple of hours and kind help of [Kyslik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564365/kyslik) I was able to find the clue of this issue. Actually what did helped me is debugging and looking up the error I get. Eventually I found following post (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1413#issuecomment-222031665) which states kind of strange thing:

> Guzzle won't work at all if the same instance of PHP is used to send the Request from Guzzle, and to respond that request

I moved everything to hosting and it worked like a charm. Hope that will help someone in future.

Thanks everyone who envolved finding solution and of course to [Kyslik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564365/kyslik)!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `json` option in the Guzzle options in your POST request instead of the `form_params`.

```
public function connect()
{
    $loginResult = $this->client->request('POST', config('api.base_uri') .'/auth/login', [
        'json' => [
            'email' => config('api.login'),
            'password' => config('api.password'),
        ]
    ]);

    dd(json_decode($loginResult->getBody()));

}
```

`form_params` should be used with non-json endpoints.

More information on the `json` property: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#uploading-data

**EDIT** an example for an endpoint that accepts `form-params` but returns JSON, which might be what you have:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new Client()
    $this->connect();
}

public function connect()
{
    $loginResult = $this->client->request('POST', config('api.base_uri') .'/auth/login', [
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => config('api.login'),
            'password' => config('api.password'),
        ]
    ]);

    dd(json_decode($loginResult->getBody()));

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, same result 401 :(

Comment: Hmm, then maybe you don't have an JSON endpoint at all. Try changing the `json` key back to `form-params` _and_ removing the Headers related to `json` fields.

Comment: that is what I started from - without headers... sorry for misleading you... same result

Comment: removed it from initial question - that is obvoius wrong anyway. thanks for spotting ;)

Comment: Weird! What's the exact HTTP status code Guzzle's response is giving you? `$loginResult->getStatusCode();`

Comment: Also what does `dd(config('api.base_uri').'/auth/login');` give you? Is it the correct URL?

Comment: URL 100% correct I checked symbol-by-symbol... Unfortunately I got just exception: `Client error: `POST http://********.local/api/auth/login` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"Unauthorized"}` I have updated initial question with Controller function which hit this request (it also does)

Comment: In the controller that's accepting the request, can you do a `dd($request->input());` and see if you're receiving the correct credentials? I'm assuming you're using Laravel and you have control of the controller.

Comment: `dd($request->input())` is `null`. However (see updated code in question end) in this line: `return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized '.$credentials['email']], 401);` I receiving correct email

Comment: Can you show the results of `dd($credentials);` without the sensitive information?

Comment: for some reason it is `null`

Comment: @AleksandrPopov Show `dd($request->all())`.

Comment: @Kyslik same - `null`... have no idea why

Comment: Can you show the route from the routes file? There may be a middleware or something that's messing with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan config:cache` on both sites to solve this problem.

> Two sites on Apache on Windows requires cached configurations. It's a known but non-documented problem. Run php artisan config:cache on both sites.

Src: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21533#issuecomment-334352170